# Text-shadow overlays webkit gradient

Tags: html, css

I have a [website](http://conilanalaindia.com/prueba/index.html) and I'm trying to add a gold effect to the word India. I've tried two options: canvas and webkit-gradient. The problem with the canvas is that it doesn't appear on the same line. I have also tried it with the webkit-gradient kind of like [this](https://codepen.io/guestn/pen/cIoqL)

```
h1, h2  {
    color: #D5AD6D; /*if no support for background-clip*/
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), 
    -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(213,173,109,1) 0%, rgba(213,173,109,1) 26%, rgba(226,186,120,1) 35%, rgba(163,126,67,1) 45%,  rgba(145,112,59,1) 61%, rgba(213,173,109,1) 100%); 
background: -o-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent); 
    -webkit-background-clip: text;   
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

or even with an *after* section but the text-shadow always overlays the gradient.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by `text-shadow` set on `h1`.

To fix it you could simply set

```
span {
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Miss+Fajardose');

span {
color: #D5AD6D; /*if no support for background-clip*/
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), 
-webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(213,173,109,1) 0%, rgba(213,173,109,1) 26%, rgba(226,186,120,1) 35%, rgba(163,126,67,1) 45%,  rgba(145,112,59,1) 61%, rgba(213,173,109,1) 100%); 
background: -o-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent); 
-webkit-background-clip: text;   
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
} 

h1 {
  font-family: "Miss Fajardose", cursive;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 90px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  /* Text shadow is causing the problem! */
  /*text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;*/
}
```

```html
<h1>Con Ilan a la <span>India</span></h1>
```

Comment: But I want it to have a text shadow. Would I add it directly as a style on the html?